# Mips assembly swap elements of an arrray

Tags: assembly, mips

Hello i have an assignment to write an Mips function that takes that swaps the elements v[i] and v[j] of an array v. The i is stored in $a0 and j in $a1. My code right now is the following:

```
swap:                           # swap entry point
    la      $t4, v
    sll     $t1, $a0, 2
    add     $t1, $t1, $t4
    lw      $t0,0($t1)
    
    sll     $t1, $a1, 2
    add     $t1, $t1, $t4
    lw      $t2, 0($t1)
    
    sw      $t3, 0($t0)
    sw      $t0, 0($t2)
    sw      $t2, 0($t3)
    
    
    jr      $ra             # return to caller
```

I get exceptions 5(address error in store) and exception 7(bad data access0)
what could be causing these issues. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: one of your stores is using `$t0` as the data, right after a previous one used it as the address.  That makes no sense for this function.  Also, you have 3 stores, but a swap should only write each location once (after loading them both.)  Use the debugger to look at what addresses you're calculating, and what's in those registers by the time you want to reuse the address calculations for the stores.

Comment: You're also sourcing `$t3` without ever having put a value there.

Comment: You wipe out `$t1` holding the original pointer in order to compute the next pointer, but you need both later on in order to accomplish the stores.  Try running this on some real or hypothetical data.

Comment: You can find all of these problems by stepping through the code instruction by instruction in the debugger and looking at what's in each of the registers at each instruction.